# Problems loading yahoo and others

Tags: 12.04, dns, yahoo

I have been having issues with several websites saying "server not found", and I have ruled out proxy issues as the cause.  From what I have found while looking for assistance, my problem likely lies with DNS.

If you have Ubuntu 12.04, and can both load and use Yahoo mail, please post the contents of the following folder so I can compare mine to yours and hopefully resolve my issue.  Also, please post the full text of the files within the folder as seen through the Text Editor App.

File System - etc - dhcp3

Comment: Is the Ubuntu 12.04 machine your only computer? Have you done a sequential power cycle of your router and modem, making sure the modem came back up for 30 secs before you turned the router back on?

Comment: Seems that you have two accounts. I recommend you to register one and ask for your accounts to be merged. Just click the [Contact us](http://askubuntu.com/contact) button.

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out, if unable to load Yahoo and similar sites, and unsure of DNS on own computer, set a static IP for your computer(which I did).  Now it all works, even after a reboot.